# Dynamically setState() with key nested state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method in a component. I want to dynamically setState with a key in a nested array of objects.

```
method = (name, value) => {
    console.log(name)
    //a  //value is 1
    //b  //value is 2
    //c  //value is 3
    this.setState({ [name]:value })
}
```

when its not nested, it dynamically changes state successfully. However when its nested

```
 method = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({
        ArrayOfObjects:[{
            [name] : value
    }]
 }
```

My state becomes

```
state = {
    ArrayOfObjects: [{
       c: 3
    }]
}
```

I want

```
state = {
    ArrayOfObjects: [{
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    }]
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Is `ArrayOfObjects` **always** an array with just a single (1) object like in your example? If not, does each object have some sort identifier to signal where a given `name` and `value` need to be added as property/value to? For example if becomes `{ ArrayOfObjects: [{ a:1 }, { a:1, b:2 }] }`, which object in the array would `name` of `c` and `value` of `3` go to?

Comment: ArrayOfObjects is always a single object

Comment: Can I ask why you would need `ArrayOfObjects` to be an array if it's only going to ever have a single object?

Comment: I'm using semantic ui and I want to render table rows dynamically. The table component has a jsx attribute tableData which must take an array of objects. Its passed into the renderBodyRow to be mapped

Answer (score 1):

You could just push an element to the current ArrayOfObjects.

```
ArrayOfObjects = this.state.ArrayOfObjects;
ArrayOfObjects.push({[name] : value});
this.setState({
    ArrayOfObjects
});
```

Or using the spread operator:

```
this.setState({
    ArrayOfObjects: [
        ...this.state.ArrayOfObjects,
        {[name] : value}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ArrayOfObjects` is an always an array with single object and that you want to merge `name`/`value` into that object:

```
method(name, value) {
  // make a copy
  const ArrayOfObjects = [...this.state.ArrayOfObjects];
  // merge properties and set dynamic value
  ArrayOfObjects[0] = { ...ArrayOfObjects[0], [name]: value };

  this.setState({
    ArrayOfObjects
  });
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9yng3y) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using spread operator, same problem. Probably something wrong with my code. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you review the linked example? You can add name/value and merge it into `ArrayOfObjects` without losing any properties or affecting other values in state. The key thing here is targeting the first element in the `ArrayOfObjects` array. It's different than `ArrayOfObjects:[{ [name] : value }]` as that will always replace the existing object entirely and not merge the properties.

Comment: Yup, I reviewed it. My method is only changing the state of the last name/value pair that's passed in. It may be because I'm using ref in my form to capture input value instead. I felt it was better to capture the value when the user submits the form rather than onChange. Is this wrong?

Comment: I only added `onChange` because there wasn't any information provided regarding how `method(name, value)` is called or how it retrieves the values. It's just being used in the example as a mechanism to pass a `name` and `value` to `method(name, value)` in an interactive way to demonstrate the functionality of the `setState()` updating and merging state. All the `onChange` really does is pass values to `method(name, value`)`, it can really be ignored.